# MySQL: выбрать записи, у которых значение поля меньше, чем значение этого поля у предыдущей записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Рассмотрим таблицу, хранящую баланс пользователя на разные моменты времени:

```
//MySQL id/time/summa
15 | 13576132115 | 5000
16 | 13576132116 | 4000
17 | 13576132117 | 8000
18 | 13576132118 | 2000
19 | 13576132119 | 9000
20 | 13576132120 | 5000
```

Как выбрать записи, которые уменьшали баланс пользователя, в одном запросе? Конечно, можно в массиве все перебрать, но хочется за 1 запрос сделать. MySQL так умеет? Хочется в итоге увидеть что-то в таком духе:

```
//MySQL какой-то волшебный запрос
16 | 13576132116 | -1000
18 | 13576132118 | -6000
20 | 13576132120 | -4000
```

Comment: @mixalef, расскажите подробнее, как именно у вас хранится информация по балансу и информация об операциях с балансом?

Comment: ну вот допустим запись 15, id/дата/сумма. Сумма 5000р. Человек пришел, ему сняли 1000р. Значит 16я запись будет - 5000-1000=4000р. Вот ее и добавляю, с 4000р

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предположить, время возрастает с возрастанием `id` (то есть каждое новое вставленное время больше или равно предыдущему), то нужный вам запрос выглядит так:

```
select b1.summa - b2.summa as amount
from ballance b1
join ballance b2 on b1.id = b2.id + 1
having amount < 0;
```

Если `id` идут не подряд, а с перерывами (1, 2, 5, 6, 8), то вместо `id` можно использовать номер строки. Полного аналога `rownum` из Oracle в MySQL нет, но можно использовать [такой трюк](http://www.sql.ru/forum/220611/analog-rownum).