# Использование самосоединения таблиц в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

[Тут темка была, буквально 2 часа назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245887/php-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-mysql), и он даже вроде как принят. Но до меня не дошла глубокая мысль той темы.

Создал 1 в 1 таблицу в MySQL, делаю запрос (прям в PHPmyadmin).

> Ошибка: Неизвестный столбец 'b1.summa'.

Я понимаю, что я не ас в MySQL, но может кто объяснить, как этот запрос сделать валидным для MySQL ?

P.S. примерно такой синтаксис годится для SQL, но не для MySQL. Вот ищу как приспособить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть запроса [[@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton)](/users/5577/fori1ton) - использование алиасов. Алиасы позволяют одну и ту же таблицу (и одни и те же поля, кстати) добавлять в запрос несколько раз.

Переформулируем (возможно, так запрос [[@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton)](/users/5577/fori1ton) будет более понятным):

```
SELECT b1.summa - b2.summa AS amount
  FROM ballance AS b1, 
       ballance AS b2
 WHERE b1.id = b2.id + 1
HAVING amount < 0;
```

Обратите внимание, что таблица *ballance* в запросе указывается дважды - как *b1* и *b2*.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, ааа... все. дошло. Спросил немного не корректно, но каким то образом ответ в точку!